# Toggle visibility of all divs at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

i have multiple divs with id = e. also multiple divs with id = b. now i want to **hide all divs with id e** and **show all divs with id b**. this should be done using **toggle**. so that again clicking on button shows **all divs with id e** and hides **all divs with id b**.

```
<script>
            function toggle_visibility(e, b) {  
   var e = document.getElementById(e);
   var e2 = document.getElementById(b);
   if(e.style.display == 'none') {                
      e.style.display = 'inline-block'; //block will show the conain in div            
      e2.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else {
      e.style.display = 'none';            
      e2.style.display = 'inline-block';
   }              
}
        </script>
        <style>
            .menu{
                display:inline-block;
                border:1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: black;
                width:auto;
                height:30px;
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 2px;
            }
        </style>
        <a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility('e', 'b');">Change</a>

        <div id="e" class="menu">Male</div><div id="b" class="menu" style="display: none;">পুরুষ</div>

        <div id="e" class="menu">Female</div><div id="b" class="menu" style="display: none;">মহিলা</div>
```

Comment: Dont you think `id` should be unique?. You should target using a class instead

Comment: `ID Should be unique` use `class` for this matter

Comment: From MSDN: id `The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.` class `The class global attribute is a space-separated list of the classes of the element. Classes allows CSS and Javascript to select and access specific elements`

Comment: changed that.. not worked ..

Comment: Then show your changes - or this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` for any `element` in a HTML page has to be `unique` as per `W3C rules`. I would suggest rather to add a separate class to your each `div` which has to be common. Say, add `classA` to `divs` whose `id` has to be `e` and `classB` to `divs` whose `id` has to be `b`.

```js
$(".toggleVisible").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.classA,.classB').slideToggle(); 
  //slideToggle will toggle whichever hidden to display and vice versa
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toggleVisible">Change</a>

<div class="menu classA">Male</div>
<div class="menu classB" style="display: none;">পুরুষ</div>

<div class="menu classA">Female</div>
<div class="menu classB" style="display: none;">মহিলা</div>
```

**Javascript version**

```js
function toggle_visibility() {
  var e = document.getElementsByClassName("classA");//returns an array of elements
  //Assuming that you will have equal amount of classA and classB elements
  var e2 = document.getElementsByClassName("classB");
  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i].style.display == 'none') {
      e[i].style.display = 'inline-block'; //block will show the conain in div            
      e2[i].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      e[i].style.display = 'none';
      e2[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle_visibility()">Change</a>

<div class="menu classA">Male</div>
<div class="menu classB" style="display: none;">পুরুষ</div>

<div class="menu classA">Female</div>
<div class="menu classB" style="display: none;">মহিলা</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use id as multiple ! **So move your id value to as class name**

```
function toggle_visibility(e, b) {  
   var e = document.getElementsByClassName(e);
   var e2 = document.getElementsByClassName(b);
   for(var i =0;i<e.length;i++){
     if(e[i].style.display == 'none') {                
        e[i].style.display = 'inline-block'; //block will show the conain in div            
        e2[i].style.display = 'none';
     }
     else {
        e[i].style.display = 'none';            
        e2[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
     }              
  }
}
```

If you want to do in Jquery ,there is no need parameters I think..

```
function toggle_visibility() {  
  $('.e').toggle();
  $('.b').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` has to be unique...You can target multiple elements using having common `class` name like so:

```js
     function toggle_visibility(e, b) {
       var e = $(".e");
       var e2 = $(".b");
       if (e.is(":visible")) {
         e2.show();
         e.hide();
       } else {
         e2.hide();
         e.show();
       }
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#id" onclick="toggle_visibility('e', 'b');">Change</a>

<div id="e" class="menu e">Male</div>
<div id="b" class="menu b" style="display: none;">পুরুষ</div>

<div id="e" class="menu e">Female</div>
<div id="b" class="menu b" style="display: none;">মহিলা</div>
```